# Leverage Browser Caching

Tags: php, optimización

He probado varios test de optimización de páginas online y uno de ellos me da este error que no sé como solucionar...

**Leverage Browser Caching**

No sé que es esto y como solucionarlo, sinceramente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**--------------------------------------**

¿Alguien Sabría solucionar este problema?

Muchas gracias adelantadas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución a Leverage Browser Caching**

He estado mirando más detenidamente y he encontrado este post que explica el problema que conlleva Leverage Browser Caching. https://ayudawp.com/leverage-browser-caching/

La solución, o mejor dicho una posible solución, es definir en el archivo .htaccess el tiempo de almacenaje en la caché de los tipos de archivos.

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Y desarrollando más la respuesta, podríamos definir, o eso he entendido, que hay que especificar al navegador cada cuanto tiempo debe almacenar los archivos en la caché del navegador, ya que de lo contrario cada vez que visitases la página te volvería a descargar todos los archivos, por lo cual el tiempo de carga de la página aumenta y la página no esta optimizada, lo cual perjudica en el SEO.

Por ello, especificandolo en el archivo .htaccess, le decimos al navegador que cada X tiempo descarge los tipos de archivos y los almacene en la caché.

Espero que haya quedado un poco más claro. Para más información al respecto, o mejor dicho, para información "veraz", visita el enlace que he puesto arriba.

Un saludo!